# array_filter and different http responses

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following code which returns some articles. Sometime they should be filtered and I have a method `filterByDate` for that

```
 $articles = Article::find()->where(['type' => $type])->orderBy([
     'priority' => SORT_ASC,'created_at' => SORT_DESC
 ])->all();

 $filtered_articles = $type == 'race' ? $this->filterByDate($articles): $articles;

 if(!empty($filtered_articles)){
    return $this->prepareResponse('success', '', $filtered_articles);
 } else {
    return $this->prepareResponse('error', 'No articles');
 }
```

Here is an implementation of method:

```
private function filterByDate($articles) {
    if(!is_array($articles) || empty($articles)) {
        return [];
    }

    return array_filter($articles, function($article) {
        return $this->checkArticleAvailability($article);
    });
}
```

A little strange behavior here in responses. If array wan't checked by  `filterByDate` response is OK, it is an array:

[image]

but if it was handled with `filterByDate` it returns an object:

[image]

I've checked code with debugger and in both cases there is an array type on server side but different result in browser.

So would be interesting to find out an explanation for that behavior.

Comment: It looks like bug in `prepareResponse()`.

Comment: Just found comment in PHP docs  - "Because array_filter() preserves keys, you should consider the resulting array to be an associative array even if the original array had integer keys for there may be holes in your sequence of keys. This means that, for example, json_encode() will convert your result array into an object instead of an array. Call array_values() on the result array to guarantee json_encode() gives you an array." https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php#99358